# Perform Denial of Service attack

Tags: ddos, denial-of-service, hping

I'm learning networking and internet security, and I'm trying a perform a `Denial-of-Service` attack on a `VM(ip-address:192.168.100.1)`  who act as a gateway.
Following some tutorials,I'm using `hping3` to perform this with `hping3 -S --flood -V -p 80 192.168.100.1` as command.
Still I'm able to ping to the gateway from another host.
I've tried to add another attacker,and open more terminals,still no success, the one thing I have obtained is an increment of the round-trip-time ( about 90ms).

Are the attackers too few to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOS may be illegal (in many countries). I write this just for educational purpose

Yes you will need more attacker instances. It is highly unlikely that the attacker has a single machine with a big enough Internet connection to generate enough traffic on its own. One way to generate that much traffic is through a botnet.

You may refer to the following link as the 1st step:

```
https://blog.cloudflare.com/65gbps-ddos-no-problem/
```